Kubernetes kustomize configmap
I have to deploy app in kubernetes cluster,
There are different environment like dev , stg , prod.
Each environment has different configmap.
So using kustomize to create manifest files from the base file.
I want to generate the configmap for each environment.
The below is the code for the base configmap,
I want to override the CTRL_DB_IP for each environment.
I want to use the configmap Generator. Need help on how to parse this CTRL_DB_IP for different environment.

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: controller-application-properties-configmap
  namespace: controller
data:
  application-ctr.properties: |
    spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true
    server.shutdown=graceful
    spring.banner.location=classpath:banner.txt
        
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${CTRL_DB_IP}:3306/scloud?serverTimezone=UTC



There are many variable to be orer written from the base file.

please correct typos and ask a specific question.

Looks like CTRL_DB_IP is expected to be an environment variable. How are you setting these env vars?

Use a shell script:
#!/bin/bash

for envir in dev stg prod;
do
  export CTRL_DB_IP="...."

  sed "s/\$CTRL_DB_IP\$/$CTRL_DB_IP/g" yourconfigmap.yaml  | kubectl apply -n $envir -f -
done

the file yourconfigmap.yaml should contain the following text:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: controller-application-properties-configmap
  namespace: controller
data:
  application-ctr.properties: |
    spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true
    server.shutdown=graceful
    spring.banner.location=classpath:banner.txt
        
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$CTRL_DB_IP$:3306/scloud?serverTimezone=UTC

